# Programmatically selecting non adjacent Cells

Tags: front-end, notebooks, cells

One can of course <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + `MouseClick` to select 1st and 3rd cell.

**But how to select non adjacent Cells programmatically**?

I was looking for *neat examples* here or in the documentation but I was not able to find suitable `Option` / function / `FrontEndToken`.

---

The method I've prepared is good enough for many cases so I'm posting it as an answer but I will gladly accept other if it deals with following issues:

- Using my method, to **expand** selection one need to rescan all already selected. Not really efficient.

and a minor issues

- This is ugly big amout of code for such simple operation.
- I was not able to manipulate `CellTags` with `CurrentValue`. Not quite sure why.

Answer (score 8):

So the only way that came to my mind and worked was to use `CellTags` and `NotebookLocate`.

```
SetAttributes[selectCells, HoldRest];

selectCells[cells_, nb_: InputNotebook[]] := With[{
  tag = ToString @ Unique["Tag"]
  },
  (SelectionMove[#, All, Cell, AutoScroll -> False]; 
   FrontEndExecute@FrontEnd`SelectionAddCellTags[nb, tag]
  ) & /@ cells;
  NotebookLocate[tag];
  FrontEndExecute@FrontEnd`SelectionRemoveCellTags[nb, tag]   
];
```

This only works with current `InputNotebook[]` so you can use it in the notebook which is `a parent to cells` you want to select or you can use it `from palette`.

---

For testing purposes evaluate:

```
selectCells @ Cells[][[{1, 3}]]
```

or

```
 selectCells @ Cells[][[;; ;; 2]]
```

and the result should be something like:

> [image]

Comment: Personally I prefer a `NotebookFind` to a `NotebookLocate` because I can more easily specify which notebook to so the selection in.

Comment: @b3m2a1 It think your preference is indeed better. I must have missed that commands like `NotebookFind[nb, "tag", All, CellTags]` work. Quite often my self answers are imperfect as I need stuff to be done and proceed with other duties. Will update this answer soon.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of selecting cells and then using the `` FrontEnd`SelectionAddCellTags `` / `` FrontEnd`SelectionRemoveCellTags `` functions, you can just use [`SetOptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetOptions) on the [`CellObject`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CellObject) (i.e., no need to select them first). Here is a version of `selectCells` that does this:

```
selectCells[cells_List]:=With[
    {
    tmp = CreateUUID[],
    parents = DeleteDuplicates @ Map[ParentNotebook] @ cells
    },
    Internal`WithLocalSettings[
        addCellTag[cells, tmp],
        NotebookFind[#1, tmp, All, CellTags]& /@ parents,
        removeCellTag[cells, tmp]
    ]
]

addCellTag[cells_, tag:_String|{__String}] := With[
    {
    new = Flatten /@ Thread[{CurrentValue[cells, CellTags], Sequence@@tag}]
    },
    MapThread[SetOptions[#1, CellTags->#2]&, {cells, new}]
]

removeCellTag[cells_, tag:_String|{__String}] := With[
    {
    new = DeleteCases[
        Flatten @* List /@ CurrentValue[cells, CellTags],
        Alternatives @@ tag,
        {2}
    ]
    },
    MapThread[SetOptions[#1, CellTags->#2]&, {cells, new}];
]
```

It uses some of the ideas behind @b3m2a1's [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/154374/45431) to essentially the same question, e.g., [`CreateUUID`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CreateUUID) (to create a unique tag), [`NotebookFind`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NotebookFind) (so that it works with cells from any notebook) and [`ParentNotebook`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParentNotebook) (to figure out what notebooks contain the cells).