# How to select two adjacent cells at the same time?

Tags: front-end, notebooks, cells, customization

I can select the first cell like this:

```
nb = CreateDocument[{a, b, c}, WindowTitle -> "Other"];
SelectionMove[nb, Next, Cell]
```

[image]

But how to select the first and the second cell?

Comment: closely related: [Programmatically selecting non adjacent Cells](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/71897/5478)

Comment: @Kuba Little complex.Thanks :)

Comment: @Kuba Maybe we can simulate lick Ctrl then move??

Comment: We can ([**30695**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30695/5478)) but you'd have to know where :) And as far as I'm concerned there is no way to do this withing MMA only, based on CellObject.

Answer (score 2):

Ah, now I recall why I emphasized "non adjacent" in [Programmatically selecting non adjacent Cells](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/71897/5478)

It is because **you can select adjacent cells** by mimicking what FE does when you use keyboard shortcuts:

> ```
> Item[KeyEvent["Down", Modifiers -> {Shift}], "SelectNextLine"],
> ```
>
> -KeyEventTranslations.tr

So in our case:

- Select the first cell for a set you want to select
- Repeat token execution

```
SelectionMove[First @ Cells[], All, Cell]
FrontEndExecute @ FrontEndToken["SelectNextLine"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create the Notebook with tags and later evaluate those. Notebooklocate also works with stored notebooks. Consider that the Cells maybe only are evaluateable if the type is set to "Input".

```
nb1 = CreateDocument[{Cell["a=2", "Input", CellTags -> "myTag"], 
   Cell["b"], Cell["c=3d", "Input", CellTags -> "myTag"]}, 
  WindowTitle -> "myCreation"]    

SetSelectedNotebook[nb1]
NotebookLocate["myTag"]
SelectionEvaluate[nb1]
```

Comment: No one said anything about evaluation :)

Comment: Well, if one drops the last Part (SelectionEvaluate) it will only select the cells. I didn't thougth someone would only want to select severel cells without processing them.

Comment: I see, but one may want to delete them, or change a background. Maybe you are right but I'm afraid the question is more general, so e.g. OP may want to select cells 1,2, do something, and the select cells 1,3.